# Understanding ROLLUP in SQL

Tags: sql

I've figured out CUBE as just generating all the permutations, but I am having trouble with ROLLUP. There don't seem to be any good resources online or in the book I'm reading for explaining SQL for people like me who struggle with it.

My book says that ROLLUP is a special case of the CUBE operator that excludes all cases that don't follow a hierarchy within the results.

I'm not entirely sure what it means, but running it on a table I made kinda produces some useful results.

I made a table from another page on google like this:

```
Type        Store       Number
Dog     Miami       12
Cat     Miami       18
Turtle   Tampa       4
Dog     Tampa       14
Cat     Naples      9
Dog     Naples      5
Turtle   Naples      1
```

Then here is query I made:

```
select store,[type], SUM(number) as Number from pets

group by store, [type]

with rollup
```

This shows me the number of each type of pet in each store, and total pets in each store, which is kinda cool. If I want to see the query based on pets, I found I have to switch the group by order around so type comes first.

So is rollup based on the first group by clause?

The other question is, I read you use ROLLUP instead of CUBE when you have a year and month column to stop it aggregating the same month across multiple years. I think I understand what this means, but could anyone clarify it? And how do you set it up like this?

Can you use ROLLUP to exclude other combinations of columns as well? My table above is quite simple and the query shows you "pets by store", but if there were other columns, could you include/exclude them from the results?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Best explained through an example. Suppose you group by `A`, `B`, `C`. You then get the following groupings with rollup:

```
(A, B, C)
(A, B)
(A)
()
```

So you see that the order is important, as you already found out. If you group by `A`, `C`, `B`, you get the following groupings instead:

```
(A, C, B)
(A, C)
(A)
()
```

Comment: Oh wow that makes it massively easier to understand! Wish they had just put that in the textbook. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, I was waiting for an answer for using rollup to exclude other combinations of columns, but I actually found the answer to that with grouping sets so yep. You should write textbooks because the first half of your answer alone told me more than my textbook and a ton of googling!

Answer (score 0):

---

---

SELECT departments.department_name
FROM departments
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_history
ON departments.department_id = job_history.department_id
WHERE job_history.employee_id IS NULL;
ex.3
SELECT department_id, manager_id, COUNT(*) as Numar
FROM Employees
GROUP BY ROLLUP(department_id, manager_id)
UNION
SELECT department_id, manager_id, COUNT(*) as Numar
FROM Employees
GROUP BY ROLLUP(manager_id, department_id);

SELECT department_id, manager_id, COUNT(employee_id) as employee_count
FROM employee
GROUP BY ROLLUP (department_id, manager_id);

---

SELECT employee_id, first_name, manager_id
FROM employee
START WITH employee_id = :employee_id
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

ex3.1SELECT department_id, manager_id, COUNT(*) as Numar
FROM Employees
GROUP BY ROLLUP(department_id, manager_id)
UNION
SELECT department_id, manager_id, COUNT(*) as Numar
FROM Employees
GROUP BY ROLLUP(manager_id, department_id);