# Oracle ROLLUP - Introductory explanation?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, oracle-xe, rollup

I've searched (but can't find) a very basic/introductory explanation of Oracle 11g's `ROLLUP`. From the queries below, it appears that I'm supplied subtotals for any expressions **not** included in the `ROLLUP` clause. Is this correct?
I'd appreciate a **basic and detailed** explanation.

EDIT: Just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156424/understanding-rollup-in-sql%20this%20post) - helped a little, but I'm still not quite there.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT department_id, job_id, SUM(salary) FROM employees
WHERE department_id > 89
GROUP BY department_id, job_id;
```

**Result 1**

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    JOB_ID     SUM(SALARY)
110              AC_ACCOUNT 8300
90               D_VP       34000
110              AC_MGR     12008
90               AD_PRES    24000
100              FI_MGR     12008
100              FI_ACCOUNT 39600
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT department_id, job_id, SUM(salary) FROM employees
WHERE department_id > 89
GROUP BY department_id, ROLLUP(job_id);
```

**Result 2**

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    JOB_ID     SUM(SALARY)
90               AD_VP      34000
90               AD_PRES    24000
90                          58000
100              FI_MGR     12008
100              FI_ACCOUNT 39600
100                         51608
110              AC_MGR     12008
110              AC_ACCOUNT 8300
110                         20308
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, following statements are equivalent

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3, ROLLUP(YEAR, MONTH);

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3, YEAR, MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), YEAR, NULL AS MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3, YEAR
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SID), NULL AS YEAR, NULL AS MONTH, flag1, flag2, flag3
FROM a_table
GROUP BY flag1, flag2, flag3;
```

Ok,take your example:

```
SELECT department_id, job_id, SUM(salary) FROM employees
WHERE department_id > 89
GROUP BY department_id, ROLLUP(job_id);
```

Is exactly the same as

```
SELECT department_id, job_id, SUM(salary) FROM employees
WHERE department_id > 89
GROUP BY department_id, job_id
Union all
SELECT department_id, NULL as job_id, SUM(salary) FROM employees
WHERE department_id > 89
GROUP BY department_id;
```

Comment: Thanks - any chance of a simpler example? I'm relatively new to SQL.

Comment: It is a simple example, it explains the ROLLUP clause conpared to do it without it